# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' - python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

In my code .text is working fine in 3rd line but giving

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

error for last line. Both are same but what might be the problem?

```
for elem6 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo'):   
       drugcodeSystem.append(elem6.find('productCode/codeSystem'))
       drugname.append(elem6.find('productCode/displayName').text)  
       routecode.append(elem6.find('routeCode/code'))   
       routecodeSystem.append(elem6.find('routeCode/codeSystem'))   
       drugname1.append(elem6.find('productCode/codeSystemName').text)
```

Comment: in 3rd line, its displayName, in 6th line its codeSystemName. In 6th line you are getting a list which is not the case in 3rd line.

Comment: codeSystemName also has some values, how to display them?

Comment: if its a list, you would need to traverse the list in a loop. try to print 'elem6.find('productCode/codeSystemName')

Comment: <Element 'codeSystemName' at 0x0000023448F6FD18> it is printing like this, instead  of value.

Comment: So its an object. You need to check all the methods this object have and then you can get the values. You can check all the methods by doing - ' dir(elem6.find('productCode/codeSystemName')) ... also try to traverse this object in a loop and then use 'text' function for each value in loop.

Comment: dir() is giving some unexpected output.